# How to set reverse DNS in AWS for my private nameserver?

Tags: amazon-web-services, reverse-dns

I wanted to set rDNS for AWS for my mail server. I have created glue records, therefore my nameservers are like ns1.mydomain.com & ns2.mydomain.com. 
**Note**: My domain registrar is AWS and may mailserver will take care of DNS.

So, I followed this guide https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/route-53-reverse-dns/, but I am little confused.

Suppose my IP is 50.60.70.80.

I created a new hosted zone with the name 70.60.50.in-addr.arpa

I created a record set and added a PTR record for the SMTP server as follows
*Name field : 80.70.60.50.in-addr.arpa
Value field: mail.mydomain.com*

Now, in this hosted zone, I have 2 extra records. 
In type NS, I replaced AWS nameservers to my nameservers ns1.mydomain.com & ns2.mydomain.com.
I don't know what to do with SOA. I would be thankful for any help.

Comment: Is this mail server running in EC2 with an elastic IP address?

Answer (score 1):

You have no control over reverse DNS records for IP addresses. You don’t own the IP addresses and only the owner can set those records.

The article you linked to would rarely, if ever, work - because it would be unlikely you’ll convince your ISP to create a delegation record. What you can do is request that your ISP create a reverse PTR record for you, and that is very simple. This is assuming you are hosting your own server on a static IP address purchased from your ISP.

In the case you are hosting your server in AWS, the article linked to doesn’t apply to you at all. In that case, you request Amazon to add the PTR record for you here: https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request